# Unable to set gradient color to my custom shape border in flutter app

Tags: flutter, linear-gradients

I have created a custom shape using CustomBorder class, and I want to set a gradient color to my custom shape. Please see the below code that I have tried.

```dart
 Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              end: Alignment.topRight,
              colors: [Colors.orangeAccent, Colors.orange]
            )
          ),
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
              shape: CustomShapeBorder(),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.instagram),
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0, left: 30.0),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          )
```

> My CustomShapeBorder() class :

```dart
class CustomShapeBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  final double distanceFromWall = 12;
  final double controlPointDistanceFromWall = 5;


  @override
  // TODO: implement dimensions
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => null;

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    // TODO: implement getInnerPath
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    // TODO: implement getOuterPath
    return getClip(Size(260.0,180.0));
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    // TODO: implement paint
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    // TODO: implement scale
    return null;
  }

  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path clippedPath = new Path();

    clippedPath.lineTo(0, size.height);
    clippedPath.quadraticBezierTo(30, size.height + 10, size.width * 0.20, size.height - 50);
    clippedPath.quadraticBezierTo(70, size.height - 120, size.width * 0.40, size.height * 0.35);
    clippedPath.quadraticBezierTo(180, (size.height - (size.height* 0.6)), size.width - 40 , 32 );
    clippedPath.quadraticBezierTo(250, 0, size.width, 0);
    clippedPath.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    clippedPath.close();
    return clippedPath;
  }
}
```

**Output:(Just refer to the upper custom shape, forget the bottom one)**
[image: Image 1]

If I remove the **color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent** from  **child: Material** then the output is :

[image: Image 2]

Comment: dont use `Material` use `ShapeDecoration` in a parent `Container`

Comment: `Container(decoration: ShapeDecoration(...`

Comment: Can you please share with me the example how can I use ShapeDecoration instead of Material, because I have tried it but I got an error message saying ` The argument type ShapeDecoration can't be assigned to the parameter type 'widget'`

Comment: `Container(decoration: ShapeDecoration(...`

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

`BoxDecoration` is optimized for rectangular widgets. Since the widget here that you'd like to apply gradient is similar to a blob. It's best to use [ShapeDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ShapeDecoration-class.html) instead. Also, Material should be used as a parent Widget and not a child of a Widget.

```dart
Container(
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(...),
  child: IconButton(...),
)
```